# How to make standalone figs match the beamer's font formating?

Tags: beamer, standalone

Consider the following MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz which loads pgf
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Time division multiple access (TDMA): \(Nk + n\)

\begin{circuitikz}

    %%% antenna
    \node[shape=antenna, xscale=-1, at={(-0.5,3)}](antenna){};
    
    %%% adder
    \node[draw, thick, shape=circle, minimum size=2pt, at={([xshift=50pt]antenna.south)}](adder){\(+\)};
    
    %%% noise
    \node[below=of adder, yshift=5pt] (noise) {\(n(t)\)};
    
    %%% h(t)
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, thick, minimum width=28pt, minimum height=28pt, at={([xshift=50pt]adder.east)}](h_t){\(h \left( t \right)\)};
    
    %%% wiring
    \draw[->] (antenna.south) to (adder.west);
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (noise) to (adder.south);
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (adder.east) to (h_t.west);
    %%% sampler
    \draw[] (h_t.east) to ++(30pt,0pt) to ++(15pt,15pt);
    \coordinate (sampler_end) at ($(h_t.east) + (30pt,0pt) + (21.21pt,0pt)$);
    \draw[->] ($(sampler_end) + (-20pt,15pt)$) to[bend left]
        node[above, yshift=5pt](){\(t = (kN+n)T_s\)}
    ($(sampler_end) + (-7pt,0pt)$);
    
    \draw[->] (sampler_end) to
        node[pos=0.5, right, pos=1]() {\(x\left[ kN + n \right]\)}
    ++(30pt,0pt);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This yields

[image]

I am learning the standalone package in order to use it properly. However, when I put it in a separate file, standalone generates a different a figure with a different text formatting.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz which loads pgf
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}  

\begin{circuitikz}

%%% antenna
\node[shape=antenna, xscale=-1, at={(-0.5,3)}](antenna){};

%%% adder
\node[draw, thick, shape=circle, minimum size=2pt, at={([xshift=50pt]antenna.south)}](adder){\(+\)};

%%% noise
\node[below=of adder, yshift=5pt] (noise) {\(n(t)\)};

%%% h(t)
\node[draw, shape=rectangle, thick, minimum width=28pt, minimum height=28pt, at={([xshift=50pt]adder.east)}](h_t){\(h \left( t \right)\)};

%%% wiring
\draw[->] (antenna.south) to (adder.west);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (noise) to (adder.south);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (adder.east) to (h_t.west);
%%% sampler
\draw[] (h_t.east) to ++(30pt,0pt) to ++(15pt,15pt);
\coordinate (sampler_end) at ($(h_t.east) + (30pt,0pt) + (21.21pt,0pt)$);
\draw[->] ($(sampler_end) + (-20pt,15pt)$) to[bend left]
    node[above, yshift=5pt](){\(t = (kN+n)T_s\)}
($(sampler_end) + (-7pt,0pt)$);

\draw[->] (sampler_end) to
    node[pos=0.5, right, pos=1]() {\(x\left[ kN + n \right]\)}
++(30pt,0pt);


\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to make standalone figs match the beamer's font formating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `standalone` class has the handy `beamer` option, which will give you the desired sans serif font (it will also disable cropping the page, but you can add it back with the option of the same name).

```
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz which loads pgf
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}  

\begin{circuitikz}

%%% antenna
\node[shape=antenna, xscale=-1, at={(-0.5,3)}](antenna){};

%%% adder
\node[draw, thick, shape=circle, minimum size=2pt, at={([xshift=50pt]antenna.south)}](adder){\(+\)};

%%% noise
\node[below=of adder, yshift=5pt] (noise) {\(n(t)\)};

%%% h(t)
\node[draw, shape=rectangle, thick, minimum width=28pt, minimum height=28pt, at={([xshift=50pt]adder.east)}](h_t){\(h \left( t \right)\)};

%%% wiring
\draw[->] (antenna.south) to (adder.west);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (noise) to (adder.south);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (adder.east) to (h_t.west);
%%% sampler
\draw[] (h_t.east) to ++(30pt,0pt) to ++(15pt,15pt);
\coordinate (sampler_end) at ($(h_t.east) + (30pt,0pt) + (21.21pt,0pt)$);
\draw[->] ($(sampler_end) + (-20pt,15pt)$) to[bend left]
    node[above, yshift=5pt](){\(t = (kN+n)T_s\)}
($(sampler_end) + (-7pt,0pt)$);

\draw[->] (sampler_end) to
    node[pos=0.5, right, pos=1]() {\(x\left[ kN + n \right]\)}
++(30pt,0pt);


\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]